# XML to C# : Deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, oop

I have an XML file like this example :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfBloc xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Bloc>
    <table>
        <name>OM_MUSER</name>
    </table>
    <listColumn>
        <Column>
            <name>CODE_USER</name>
            <value>SUPER</value>
            <type>VARCHAR</type>
            <pk>1</pk>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <name>ID_MPERSONNE</name>
            <value>1</value>
            <type>INT</type>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <name>PASSWORD_USER</name>
            <value>TESTJPA</value>
            <type>VARCHAR</type>
        </Column>
    </listColumn>
</Bloc>
<!-- ... -->
</ArrayOfBloc>
```

And I can deserialize this one using this :

```
class XmlManager
{
    public static List<Bloc> ReadXML(string path)
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer reader = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Bloc>));
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
        List<Bloc> listB = new List<Bloc>();
        listB = (List<Bloc>)reader.Deserialize(file);
        file.Close();
        return listB;
    }
}

public class Bloc
{
    public Table table { get; set; }
    public List<Column> listColumn { get; set; }

    public Bloc() 
    {
        table = new Table();
        listColumn = new List<Column>(); 
    }
}

public class Table
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Column> listColumn { get; set; }

    public Table() { listColumn = new List<Column>(); }
}

public class Column
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int pk { get; set; }
    public string defaultValue { get; set; }
    public int nullable { get; set; }

    public Column() { }
}
```

But if I want to deserialize the next XML example with the same C# code, it doesn't work and I don't know why...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfBloc xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Bloc>
    <table name="OM_MUSER"/>
    <listColumn>
        <Column name="CODE_USER" value="SUPER" type="VARCHAR" pk="1"/>
        <Column name="ID_MPERSONNE" value="1" type="INT"/>
        <Column name="PASSWORD_USER" value="TESTJPA" type="VARCHAR"/>
    </listColumn>
</Bloc>
<!-- ... -->
</ArrayOfBloc>
```

Do you know what is required to do please ? 
Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: "Does not work" is not specific enough. Add either (1) the full error message you get & where it is thrown and/or (2) your expected result versus your observed result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
[XmlRoot("ArrayOfBloc")]
public class BlocContainer
{
    [XmlElement("Bloc")]
    public List<Bloc> BlocCollection { get; set; }
}


public class Table
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    public List<Column> listColumn { get; set; }

    public Table() { listColumn = new List<Column>(); }
}

public class Column
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public string value { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("pk")]
    public int pk { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("defaultValue")]
    public string defaultValue { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("nullable")]
    public int nullable { get; set; }

    public Column() { }
}
```

Deserialize to BlocContainer

```
public static List<Bloc> ReadXML(string path)
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer reader = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(BlocContainer));
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
    BlocContainer bc = null;
    bc = (BlocContainer)reader.Deserialize(file);
    file.Close();
    if(bc != null) { return bc.BlocCollection; } else { return new List<Bloc>(); }
}
```

Comment: @user3811647 I added a bit more as you weren't using the `[XmlAttribute(...)]` attribute to declare the source of the values as the attributes.